# Trying to update from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS but unmet perl dependencies or conflicts when updating packages

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, perl

I've done: `sudo apt update`
But when I do `sudo apt upgrade`, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl-modules-5.22 : Conflicts: perl-modules
                     Conflicts: perl-modules:i386
```

I've tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get  install --reinstall perl-modules-5.22

sudo apt-get clean
```

Can't `sudo do-release-upgrade` until I get this fixed.

How do I resolve the perl conflicts?

Thanks!

Comment: Try uninstalling the `perl-modules` package, which was removed from Ubuntu sometime after 14.04.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on when you only give us bits and pieces of the output of your commands... Keep in mind that 16.04 doesn't get standard support and hasn't for over 6 months. That means it doesn't get updates and it also means that there is no longer a supported upgrade path.  Theoretically you can sign up for ESM so you can get the updates you need to upgrade to 18.04, but this assumes the problem has to do with not getting updates and dependencies. The easiest/fastest/cleanest path forward is probably to install 18.04 cleanly. Don't wait until it goes EOL to upgrade.

Comment: Like @user535733 said, remove the perl-modules package. This will resolve the conflict and let you continue with the upgrade

Answer (score 9):

@user535733: you're the man! it helped.

To be precise: you can't remove virtual package (which perl-modules are) - instead:

```
apt remove perl-modules-5.22
```

In my case.

Comment: just saved me from going down the rabbit hole. ty.